# How to remove words that ar less then 3 characters? PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to make a `function` to filter on a web page most used words.

Now I can fetch a HTML website and the function counts the words, filters them by most used, but can't make to work that words that are less then 3 characters would't be displayed.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://www.basketnews.lt');    
$search = array(
        '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
        '@<head>.*?</head>@siU',            // Lose the head section
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
        '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@',        // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA
        );

$contents = preg_replace($search, '', $contents);    
$result = array_count_values(
            str_word_count(strip_tags($contents), 1)
          );

arsort($result);
print_r($result);
```

How to implement additional functionality to this function?

Comment: an extra regex `\b\w{1,2}\b` should strip out anything that is less 3 (2 and 1) symbols long, but that includes any word char. Side Note: I also don't see HtmlDomParser

Comment: _“with the help of `HtmlDomParser`”_ - where exactly, I don’t see that used anywhere in the code you have shown.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question. How could I filter everything only that is plain HTML text? Now, it filters all HTML elements like classes and e.t.c

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new result with shorter words filtered out:

```
foreach($result as $k => $v) {
  if(strlen($k) > 2) {
    $result2[$k] = $v;
  }
}
print_r($result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.php.net/array-filter

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($value){
    return strlen($value) >= 3;
});
```

Everything that doesnt match the check gets filtered out.